# Azure Lab Services - publish a lab does not work

Tags: azure-lab-services

I can create the lab, but publishing the lab does not work.

The publication takes between 5 and 6 hours and has no result - the lab is not published afterwards. (normally the publishing lasts less then 1 hour - and it is published afterwards)
If you look into the log, you only see the entry that the publication has started.

Comment: It seems it it depends on the user doing that. In german after the unsuccessful publishing it says "Veröffentlichung aufgehoben" in english simply "Unpublished".

Comment: Seems like there is a way to publish labs:
1. Create the lab with no settings
2. Publish the lab with no settings
3. Set the setting (Automatic shutdown and disconnect)
Adding the setting in an earlier step, will result in an long lasting failed publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but I wanted to let you know that this appears to be an issue with the service.  In the future, if a lab created with Azure Lab Services gets stuck in a 'publishing' state and never finishes, the best route is to raise an Azure support ticket to get Microsoft to look into & fix it.